# Builder pattern in C

Tags: c, design-patterns

Is there a way to implement the Builder design pattern in C?  I am wondering if there is a way for the Builder to set values in a structure, but then have the structure be read-only after the structure is produced by the Builder.

I looked for examples online but couldn't find any in C. Thank you.

Comment: `const struct foo *build_struct();`, then let the function mallocate memory for the struct. It will be non-`const` inside the function but `const` when visible to the outside world.

Comment: @H2CO3: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: [named initialization is possible since C99](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55828947/2932052)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern):

> ... the intention of the builder pattern is to find a solution to the telescoping constructor anti-pattern. The telescoping constructor anti-pattern occurs when the increase of object constructor parameter combination leads to an exponential list of constructors. Instead of using numerous constructors, the builder pattern uses another object, a builder, that receives each initialization parameter step by step and then returns the resulting constructed object at once.

So, one way to achieve this would be to define a builder object with an interface that allows you to describe the object you want to build. Then you provide another method that allows you to construct the target object based on that description.

Using the car example in the wikipedia page:

```
struct car;
struct car_builder;

enum CAR_OPTIONS { CAR_OPTION_NOT_AN_OPTION,
                   CAR_OPTION_SEATS, CAR_OPTION_NAVIGATION, /* ... */ };

struct car_builder * create_car_builder ();

/*
 * Positive option sets the option, negative option unsets it.
 * If the option takes a parameter, pass them in the varargs.
 */
void car_builder_option (struct car_builder *, int option, ...);

/*
 * builds a car
 */
const struct car * car_builder_construct (struct car_builder *options);

/*
 * junks the car
 */
void car_builder_destruct (const struct car *);

/* ... */
struct car_builder *options = create_car_builder();
car_builder_option(options, CAR_OPTION_SEATS, 2);
car_builder_option(options, CAR_OPTION_SPORT_CAR);
car_builder_option(options, CAR_OPTION_NAVIGATION);
car_builder_option(options, -CAR_OPTION_POWER_WINDOWS);
const struct car *car = car_builder_construct(options);
```

Returning a pointer to a `const struct car` signals to the caller that the returned object cannot be modified directly.

Comment: In fact, a full-fledged builder would look like this in practice, but the questioner seemed to me to ask only for a very limited variant.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to implement a builder design pattern in C?

This question arose when I searched for an **obvious and safe way to initialize struct members**.

I asked a C-experienced (but also Python affine) colleague about it, expecting either nothing useful, or maybe a "clever trick", but - *wow!* - what I was told was a built-in C99 feature<sup>[1]</sup>, have a look:<sup>[2]</sup>

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct X { int a, b, c; };

int main(void) {
    struct X x = {.a=1, .b=2};
    printf("x: %d %d %d\n", x.a, x.b, x.c);
    x = (struct X){.a=1, .c=3};
    printf("x: %d %d %d\n", x.a, x.b, x.c);
    // initialize a const
    // order can be changed when elements are named
    const struct X cx = {.c=3, .b=2, .a=1};
    printf("cx: %d %d %d\n", cx.a, cx.b, cx.c);
    return 0;
}
```

---

- <sup>[1]</sup> [Struct and union initialization - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization)
- <sup>[2]</sup> see the "running" demo at https://ideone.com/ouVAk4

<sub>P.S. well, const may be relative: https://ideone.com/dZMFzK</sub>

Comment: Of course, if you don't need the builder pattern, don't use it!

Comment: You are right, it's only *one* aspect of the builder pattern that I was looking for: the *naming* of elements (sometimes useful as options) at initialization.

Comment: I re-read the OP's question, and it seems clear to me the OP wants the builder to create a read-only object.

Comment: Yes, and initializing members of a const structure can be as easy. I'd consider Builder for non-trivial initialization, for instance, if creating an object needs a sequence of well coordinated steps.